# Cannot create a group in term store using powershell - current user has insufficient permissions to perform this operation

Tags: powershell, term-store

I am trying to create a term group in the Term Store in sharepoint 2013 using powershell.

Bellow you will find the powershell script that I am using plus the error that I am getting.

```
$taxonomySession=Get-SPTaxonomySession -Site "http://xs066598:3505"
$termStore=$taxonomySession.TermStores["INT00"]
$group = $termstore.CreateGroup("Site Collection-2525")
$group.Description = "My Term Group"
$termStore.CommitAll()
$group=$termStore.Groups["Site Collection-2525"]
$termSet=$group.CreateTermSet("Word Automation Term Set 2")
$termStore.CommitAll()
$termSet=$group.TermSets["Word Automation Term Set 2"]
$term1=$termSet.CreateTerm("Conversion 1",1033)
$termStore.CommitAll()
```

Error:

```
Exception calling "CreateGroup" with "1" argument(s): "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform this operat
ion."
At C:\Projects\PowershelScripts\CreateTermSet.ps1:40 char:1
+ $group = $termstore.CreateGroup("Site Collection-2525")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
```

Anyone knows what permissions do I have to give to be able to execute the powershell script?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you run your power shell as **run as administrator** ? If still the problem persists, then Run the powershell with the user which has full admin rights.

Also sometimes The error is caused by an incorrect “**TermsStore administrator account**”.

To resolve the issue:

•Go the Central Administration

•Go to : “Manage service applications” ( _admin/serviceapplications.aspx).

•Select “Managed Metadata Service” to get the Terms Store admin interface.

•In the section : “Term Store Administrators”. Add the user that you use to run sharepoint management shell

•Save the changes.

Hope it solves the issue !

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint 2013 Enterprise, I followed the steps above, but it still didn't work.

Following on from there, I went to the 'Term Store Management Tool' in Central Admin (/_layouts/15/termstoremanager.aspx) and added the user there too. This resolved the permissions issue for me.